# Is it possible to download a part of a page's html code so you can scrape it with python later?

Tags: python, html, performance, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm creating a python web scraping project where I return the ranking data of any junior tennis player from this website : [site](https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/rankings.html#tab=junior&junior-juniorListType=seeding&junior-rankListGender=M&junior-ageRestriction=Y14)

There is a selector at the bottom where you can choose how many people you see per page. If you select 100, there will be 100 pages worth of rankings (10000 players) Is there a way to download the full ranking table so I can pull ranking values from that? USTA updates rankings every Wednesday so I'm thinking I can download once a week and it will speed up the process instead of using Selenium which I'm doing right now.

I've done this so far with selenium (snippet) and it takes a while for a tournament of 32 players.

```py
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver2.get('https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/rankings.html#tab=junior&junior-juniorListType=seeding&junior-rankListGender=M&junior-ageRestriction=Y14')

    try:
        driver2.maximize_window()
        search = WebDriverWait(driver2, 35).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-9a770322f5']/div/div/div/div/input"))
        )
        search.click()
        search.send_keys(name_string)

    finally:
        pass



try:
        national_ranking = WebDriverWait(driver2, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container-c80bd54915']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/p"))
        )
        ranking_string = str(national_ranking.text)
    except:
        ranking_string = 'Error'
    finally:
        pass
```

Please forgive me if I'm ignorant as this is my first post on SO

Comment: Before you do anything like this, you should always read the [Terms of Service](https://www.usta.com/en/home/about-usta/who-we-are/national/usta-terms-of-use.html) for the site. Basically you can't legally scrape the site so don't. Respect their right to protect their own data. If you want to learn to scrape a site, there are plenty out there that you can practice on.

Comment: Not minding legal regulations, you always download websites when opening them. To display a website, the browser has to (at least temporarily) download the files. If you open the dev tools, you have the *network* tab. There are every files listed that are downloaded. You can see and copy the source code from there.

Comment: @Oysters the SO guidelines are clear. Every question is allowed and can be answered within that scope. We are not the judges that determine if the user using the information and knowledge here for illegal or legal activities. Even questions such as *hacking*  are vital. Not in terms of using it for malicious purposes but understanding the process and fixing security issues.

Comment: @tacoshy - I understand but, if I show people how to do this you and I both know it is very unethical. I just wanted to see if I could. I'm literally bypassing their entire system, faking their keys and everything. I'm not teaching someone how to do that. I am surprised by how easy it was though.

Comment: Yes, you can look at the source code in your browser and loop through specific elements with the data you are seeking. This may not necessarily be faster since you are still going to have to hit that endpoint to get the data however like you will have to with a GET request though. You're going to hit the same endpoints regardless to pull in the data, but you can scrape it from the HTML if you want.